# Problema com manipulação de arquivos txt em C++

Tags: c++, arquivo

Estou desenvolvendo um programa em C++ que deve ler os dados do teclado armazená-los com *hash*, depois de realizar a leitura ele deve possuir em seu menu principal a opção de salvar.

Consigo ler os arquivos salvar usando o *hash* e tudo.

O problema esta na hora de criar o arquivo, gostaria de fazer um for que crie os arquivos com o nome padrão, exemplo

```
data_1
data_2
data_3
assim por diante
```

Fiz este código, mas por algum motivo ele cria apenas o arquivo do índice zero e como se ficasse repetindo o nome e substituindo o arquivo 4 vezes que é o tamanho da define `TAM`;

```
void func_arquivo::cria_arquivo(){
   ofstream arquivo;
    for(int i=0;i<TAM;i++){
        char nome[TAM];
        sprintf(nome, "Data-%d.txt",i);
        arquivo.open(nome, ios::app);
        arquivo.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: qual o tamanho da variável ``TAM`` mesmo?

Comment: o tamanho da define TAM é 4!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação da função [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/):

> The size of the buffer should be large enough to contain the entire
>   resulting string (see `snprintf` for a safer version).

[Segundo o teu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/161673/problema-com-manipula%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-arquivos-txt-em-c#comment332466_161673) o tamanho do *buffer* é *4*, você está tentando guardar ao menos *10* caracteres...

Você pode aumentar a capacidade do *buffer*, por exemplo [`char nome[FILENAME_MAX]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/FILENAME_MAX/) ou usar a função [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/), onde é definido o número máximo de *bytes* que serão escritos, assim:

```
char nome[FILENAME_MAX];
// ...
snprintf(nome, FILENAME_MAX, "Data_%d.txt", i);
// ....
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/8CmuKy)</kbd>

Comment: Perfeito funcionou , só para entender então o problema era o tamanho do char em que eu estava escrevendo o nome, como ele era pequeno demais só conseguia comportar o primeiro do laço?certo?

Comment: @Eduardo Isso mesmo...

Comment: Eu perguntei ele sobre o ``TAM`` pra dar essa resposta, só que você foi mais rápido kkkkk

Comment: Mas na verdade @Eduardo, eu nem sei como rodou a primeira vez. O que aconteceu foi que você definiu um tamanho de string de valor 4, ou seja, você só poderia adicionar 4 caracteres na variável, o que não estava acontecendo pois você adicionava no mínimo 10.

Comment: Sim @ChristianFelipe, realmente eu viajei legal!!